# Adding POE to Ethernet Board

Tags: electronics, ethernet-shield

If I was to use the [Arduino A000024](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Arduino%20PDFs/A000024_Web.pdf), would I be able to add a [POE MODULE](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/3847/C11556-001+WC-PD13C050S.pdf) to the board to get a Ethernet board with POE to run my arduino project?

Comment: why not buy A100025 - Ethernet shield with POE?

Comment: Can't find a reliable reseller for that retired board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pinout is what the Ethernet shield expects, then yes. The rows of holes at an odd angle are designed for a POE board similar to that. I can't vouch for whether the pinout is correct though.  It *looks* ok, but it depends on the dimensions of the board whether it fits the existing pinout.

Comment: I found the suggested POE module on another site that fits the pinning on this board, thank you for confirming this.